# Wordpress, Admin Custom Menu Title repeat on sub menu

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, I am trying to create a custom menus in the back-end. 
I followed this http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus link to create the menus, it works but i got one minor issue.

```
Test TopLevel
    Test TopLevel
    Test Top Sub Level
    Test Top Sub Level 2
```

I want to remove the 'Test TopLevel' under the sub menus, the final structure i want like below

```
Test TopLevel    
    Test Top Sub Level
    Test Top Sub Level 2
```

Thanks to all for your time.

---

Menu code 
    http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus
    Description: Menu Test
    Author: Codex authors
    Author URI: http://example.com
    */

```
// Hook for adding admin menus
add_action('admin_menu', 'mt_add_pages');

// action function for above hook
function mt_add_pages() {
    // Add a new submenu under Settings:
    add_options_page(__('Test Settings','menu-test'), __('Test Settings','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'testsettings', 'mt_settings_page');

    // Add a new submenu under Tools:
    add_management_page( __('Test Tools','menu-test'), __('Test Tools','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'testtools', 'mt_tools_page');

    // Add a new top-level menu (ill-advised):
    add_menu_page(__('Test Toplevel','menu-test'), __('Test Toplevel','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'mt-top-level-handle', 'mt_toplevel_page' );

    // Add a submenu to the custom top-level menu:
    add_submenu_page('mt-top-level-handle', __('Test Sublevel','menu-test'), __('Test Sublevel','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'sub-page', 'mt_sublevel_page');

    // Add a second submenu to the custom top-level menu:
    add_submenu_page('mt-top-level-handle', __('Test Sublevel 2','menu-test'), __('Test Sublevel 2','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'sub-page2', 'mt_sublevel_page2');
}

// mt_settings_page() displays the page content for the Test settings submenu
function mt_settings_page() {
    echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Settings', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
}

// mt_tools_page() displays the page content for the Test Tools submenu
function mt_tools_page() {
    echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Tools', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
}

// mt_toplevel_page() displays the page content for the custom Test Toplevel menu
function mt_toplevel_page() {
    echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Toplevel', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
}

// mt_sublevel_page() displays the page content for the first submenu
// of the custom Test Toplevel menu
function mt_sublevel_page() {
    echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Sublevel', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
}

// mt_sublevel_page2() displays the page content for the second submenu
// of the custom Test Toplevel menu
function mt_sublevel_page2() {
    echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Sublevel2', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
}

?>
```

Comment: can you show me your code for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to **wordpress** you  might not aware of this.But let me tell you, Generally what ever you add as the **menu** becomes the **1st submenu**. You can notice it by installing plugin.

But you can also customize it by following code:

```
    // Hook for adding admin menus
    add_action('admin_menu', 'mt_add_pages');

    // action function for above hook
    function mt_add_pages() {
        // Add a new submenu under Settings:
        add_options_page(__('Test Settings','menu-test'), __('Test Settings','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'testsettings', 'mt_settings_page');

        // Add a new submenu under Tools:
        add_management_page( __('Test Tools','menu-test'), __('Test Tools','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'testtools', 'mt_tools_page');

        // Add a new top-level menu (ill-advised):
        add_menu_page(__('Test Toplevel','menu-test'), __('Test botlevel','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'mt-top-level-handle', null );

        // Add a submenu to the custom top-level menu:
        add_submenu_page('mt-top-level-handle', __('Test Sublevel','menu-test'), __('Test Sublevel','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'mt-top-level-handle', 'mt_sublevel_page');

        // Add a second submenu to the custom top-level menu:
        add_submenu_page('mt-top-level-handle', __('Test Sublevel 2','menu-test'), __('Test Sublevel 2','menu-test'), 'manage_options', 'sub', 'mt_sublevel_page2');
    }

    // mt_settings_page() displays the page content for the Test settings submenu
    function mt_settings_page() {
        echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Settings', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
    }

    // mt_tools_page() displays the page content for the Test Tools submenu
    function mt_tools_page() {
        echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Tools', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
    }

    // mt_sublevel_page() displays the page content for the first submenu
    // of the custom Test Toplevel menu
    function mt_sublevel_page() {
        echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Sublevel', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
    }

    // mt_sublevel_page2() displays the page content for the second submenu
    // of the custom Test Toplevel menu
    function mt_sublevel_page2() {
        echo "<h2>" . __( 'Test Sublevel2', 'menu-test' ) . "</h2>";
    }
```

Here what I have done is, I gave `null` to the `add_menu_page` and in addition to that I have given the **SAME SLUG** to the **SUB MENU** that **MENU** had.
In our case, It is `mt-top-level-handle`.

**NOTE** : With this you can not do something like :

Test TOPLEVEL
         
    Test TOP Sub Level

You need to have more than one submenu.